# want to add mandatory field mark to textboxes on window pop using jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using jqGrid 3.5.
I have created add and edit button using "navButtonAdd" instead of the pager segment. I use json and AJAX.
I am also defining the ColName and ColModel.

The Problem:  I want to show an asteric (*) by the the required field label on add or edit modal.
If I add the asterik to ColName fields it shows up on the Header of the grid. I don't want it to show on the grid header only when someone clicks add or edit I want to show the asterik on respective labels.

```
$.subscribe('rowadd', function(event,data) {


            $("#gridtable").jqGrid('editGridRow',"new",{reloadAfterSubmit:true, closeAfterAdd:false,afterSubmit:function(response,postdata){
                return isError(response.responseText);
            }});
        });

<sjg:grid id="gridtable" caption="%{getText('menu.department')}" dataType="json" 
                href="%{listurl}"
                gridModel="listMS_Departments"
                width="200"
                autowidth="true"

                pager="true" 
                pagerInput="true"
                pagerPosition="center"  
                rowList="15,30,50"
                rowNum="15"
                rownumbers="true"
                viewrecords="true"

                navigatorDelete="true"
                navigatorRefresh="true"
                navigatorEditOptions="{closeAfterEdit:false}"
                navigatorAddOptions="{
                                          reloadAfterSubmit:true,
                                          afterSubmit:function(response,postdata){
                                          return isError(response.responseText);
                                          }
                                     }"
                editurl="%{editurl}"
                onSelectRowTopics="rowselect"
                >
                <sjg:gridColumn frozen="true" id="row" name="id" index="id" title="%{getText('department.code')}"
                    sortable="true" search="true" editable="true" editrules="{required:true,custom:true,custom_func:validateCapitalAlphanumeric}" key="true" editoptions="{maxlength :3}" />
                <sjg:gridColumn name="deptNm" index="deptNm" title="%{getText('department.name')}"
                    sortable="true" editable="true" edittype="text" editrules="{required:true}" formatter="String" editoptions="{maxlength :10}"/>   
            </sjg:grid>
```

Comment: what did you try,show some code

Comment: I want to show an asteric (*) by the the required field label on add or edit modal.
If I add the asterik to ColName fields it shows up on the Header of the grid. I don't want it to show on the grid header only when someone clicks add or edit I want to show the asterik on respective labels.since the column name and textbox names are same..i want asterisk sign to appear only on textbox when i click add...

Answer (score 0):

put the `formoptions="{ elmprefix:'(*)'}"` in `sjg:gridColumn` tag